# string input to anonymous function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function

In matlab i know i can convert string into anonymous function with `str2func`.
For example;

```
s= '@(x) x.^2';
h= str2func(s);
h(2) would be 4
```

But what if i do not know the number of unknown? Let's say user of this program will enter lots of function to get a numerical solution of a system. When the user enters `x^2`, i should add `@(x)` to its beginning then convert it to a function. But in programming time i do not know how many function the user will enter with how many unknown. `@(x)` may should be `@(x,y)` as well as `@(x,y,z)`. If the user enters the number of unknowns, how can i create and add the necessary prefix at runtime?

ps: number of unknown can be any integer number.

Comment: The problem is not just detecting how many variables the user entered; you also need to detect their names. Is there some pattern? Can the user enter something like `cos(x)`? Can variable names have more than one letter?

Comment: So you want to reimplement MATLAB? Why not just have the user add the `@(x, ...)` prefix themselves?

Comment: @LuisMendo. You just shadowed the built-in name `cos` :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist well user can enter in that way, but it did not come pretty to me. I found this problem intresting

Comment: @LuisMendo the functions will be polynomial. There is no restriction for variable names but we can put if it is necessary

Comment: @ssovukluk. Variable names are very important. You had better not prepend `@(x)` to `y.^2`. That's why it is much cleaner for the user to spec out what names they want to use first. Perhaps you should just prepend the `@`.

Comment: Order of the variables is important. `@(x,y) x.^y` is very different from `@(y,x) x.^y`

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes indeed. But because it will be polynomial, i can make a ascii character scanner to get alphabets from the equation. The main problem is how to adapt the @(..) part in programming time. Or do i have any other alternative then function handle.

Comment: @LuisMendo what would you say to make a character by character scanning part and then put those characters prefix to the string? Using ascii table?

Comment: I'd use `regexp` and some `sprintf`. But how do you decide if by `x^2+y^3` the user meant `@(x,y) x^2+y^3` or `@(y,x) x^2+y^3`? they are different function

Comment: What happens when you have a polynomial of 27 variables (or 28 if you count underscores)?

Comment: Thank you for your time guys. I have good opinions now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to know not only the quantity of variables but also their names and order. An expression may read `x(c)`. Even if you know that the expression has two variables in it and are able to parse out `x` and `c`, you won't be able to tell if the user intended to define something like `@(x, c) x(c)`, `@(c, x) x(c)` or even something like `@(c, d) x(c)` where `x` is actually a function.
- Parsing the expressions just to get the names they use is something that you shouldn't have to do.
- Restricting the variable names that are allowed can be messy. If the user is expecting MATLAB syntax and you are parsing as MATLAB, why make your life harder? Also, when you introduce a restriction like one-letter variable names only, you have to ask yourself if there will ever be a situation where you need more than 27 variables.

It would be much safer all around to have the user list the names of the variables they plan on using before the function, e.g. `(x, y, pi) pi*(x^2 + y)`. Now all you have to do is prepend `@` and not worry about whether `pi` is a built-in or an argument. In my opinion the notation is quite clean.